# Calculating expected value for joint density function

Tags: probability

$$f(x,y) = 2$$ $$0<x \le y < 1$$

I want to calculate $$E(XY)$$
In order to do that, I need to know the range for $x$ and $y$. Are they both $0$ to $1$?

Comment: $Y$ has the range $[0,1]$.  while $X$ has the range $[0,Y]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range is
$$
\begin{align}
0<&x\leq y \\
0 <&y < 1
\end{align}
$$

If you're unsure about these things you can always check it, since
$$
\int\int f(x,y)dydx=1
$$
if the integrals are over the correct domains.

With 0 to 1 for both variables, we get

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^1f(x,y)dydx=\int_0^1\int_0^12dydx=2\int_0^1dx=2
$$

so it can't be 0 to 1 for both $x$ and $y$ -- integrating over the entire space should give 1. If we use 0 to 1 for $y$ and 0 to $y$ for $x$, instead we get:

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^y2dxdy=\int_0^12ydy=1.
$$

So that's a quite easy check which is useful when you're uncertain.

Comment: Could y have range x to 1 as well?

Comment: @user2472706 Yes, with $0<x<1$ in that case. I picked $y$ as the free variable because its lower limit was 0, which made the integral a little easier.